# How to lock requests for users in the same organization

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

We have a multiuser web application. Each user belongs to his/her organization and ofcourse organization can have multiple users. What I need to accomplish is autonumbering of the documents within each organization. Here is what have I written and tested so far (example below is a test case, which increases counter for each organization):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private static Dictionary<int, object> lockDictionary = new Dictionary<int, object>();
  private static readonly object locker = new object();

  public string Lock(int orgId)
  {
    string path = @"X:\org_" + orgId.ToString();

    lock (locker)
    {
      // check if orgId is in the dictionary, else add it
      if (!lockDictionary.ContainsKey(orgId))
        lockDictionary.Add(orgId, new object());
    }

    // if some other user within the same organization tries to get current counter, wait that current user finishes
    lock(lockDictionary[orgId])
    {
      string content = "1";

      // this is just testing to write to file. Actually
      // the code will be: select counter from dbo.AuthOrg where orgId = x
      // update dbo.AuthOrg set Counter = counter +1 where orgId = x;
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
      {
        string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        int counter = Convert.ToInt32(fileContent) + 1;
        content = counter.ToString();
      }

      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, content);
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
    }
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
  }
}
```

What I need **to prevent is that two users from the same organization don't make race condition on getting and incrementing organization counter**. I accomplished that by using lock.

Does upper code have any side-effects?

Application is hosted on IIS therefore `static` variables are available to all requests.

Comment: Why use a Dictionary of only keys? Use a `HashSet<int>` instead. Also, you could have used a `ConcurrentDictionary` and avoid that `lock`

Comment: Are you planning on scaling out your API at any point in the future?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto and how would lock by id with `HashSet<int>`?

Comment: @Evk Now that I think about it, you probably can't. But that shouldn't be a problem with a `ConcurrentDictionary` anyway

Comment: @john for now no. I could just put `lock` on the whole request and that's it, but performance is important to me. Although I need to check in what mode sqlserver is configured (multiple inserts at the same time...).

Comment: Your question is not quite a good fit for this site, because it works as expected. It better fits https://codereview.stackexchange.com/